# Использование конструкции ifeq в makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Хочу написать `makefile`, который бы в зависимости от наличии команды в bash использовал разные компиляторы.

Написал для проверки небольшой `makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(gcc 2> /dev/null; echo $?), 1)
    CXX=gcc
else
    CXX=clang
endif

all:
    $(CXX)
```

Который по идее должен в случае наличия компилятора `gcc` использовать `gcc`, в случае его отсутствия `clang` (если команда в bash отсутствует, то её вызов вернет `127`, то есть, например,

```
$ kek
-bash: kek: command not found
$
```

, тогда как вызов `gcc` вернет `1` и в `stderr` напишет:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

)

Однако при вызове `make` у меня используется `clang`, хотя при этом на моем компьютере присутствует `gcc` и условие из `ifeq` в `bash` равно `1`:

```
$ gcc 2> /dev/null; echo $?
1
$
```

При этом я перепробовал множество различных вариантов, например, `-n` у `echo` и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifeq ($(shell gcc -v >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?),0)
# ...
```

Ошибки в исходном варианте:

- Конструкция `$()` в `make` вызывает [функции `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Syntax-of-Functions), а не команды оболочки. Для того чтобы выполнить команду оболочки нужно воспользоваться функцией [`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).
- [`$?`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_003f-_0028automatic-variable_0029) имеет своё значение в `make`; чтобы эта переменная передавалась оболочке нужно [эскейпить](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html) её вторым долларом: `$$`.
- Надёжней проверять, что команда успешно выполнилась, а не просто умерла, вернув какой-то свой код ошибки. Для этого можно попросить программу сделать что-нибудь нудное, например распечатать свою версию, как выше.